# Android setting text inside list view using onClick with ToggleButton

Tags: android

Using list view in Android application that uses a ToggleButton to record number of times it has been pressed and display the number on each click. I can't get the View object in order to set the text using setText() to the new number each time. I can get the position using tags, but it seems to give a null pointer exception each time I use that to get the View object that I want. Maybe I am going about this completely wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
package com.eventappucsd.activity;


import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import com.eventappucsd.backend.Event;


import java.util.List;

public class EventsCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Event>  {

private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private static FragmentManager sFragmentManager;
private ContentResolver mContentResolver;
private Context mContext;
private final String LOG_TAG = EventsCustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

public EventsCustomAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager){

    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2);
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    sFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final     ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if(convertView == null) {
        //custom event layout
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_event, parent, false);

    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }
    final Event event = getItem(position);
    final int _id = event.getId();
    final String name = event.getEventName();
    final String date = event.getDate();
    final String time = event.getTime();
    final String location = event.getLocation();
    final String description = event.getDescription();
    final int numVotes = event.getNumVotes();

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_name)).setText(name);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_date)).setText(date);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_location)).setText(location);
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_numVotes)).setText(numVotes + " Votes");

    //get the context so that the object called is not null for db updates
    mContentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    /*
    make the event clickable and transition into the ViewActivity
     */
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //setting up the data needed to be made available by the ViewEventActivity.class
            Intent eventView = new Intent(getContext(), ViewEventActivity.class);
            eventView.putExtra(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_ID, String.valueOf(_id));
            eventView.putExtra(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_NAME, name);
            eventView.putExtra(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_DATE, date);
            eventView.putExtra(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_TIME, time);
            eventView.putExtra(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_LOCATION, location);
            eventView.putExtra(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_DESCRIPTION,description);
            getContext().startActivity(eventView);
        }
    });

    final ToggleButton upvoteButton = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.upbtn);
    // Needed in order to have both the button and the list item clickable
    upvoteButton.setFocusable(false);
    upvoteButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    upvoteButton.setClickable(true);
    upvoteButton.setTag(position);
    upvoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final int position = (Integer)view.getTag();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "position of view: " + position + "\n");
                //get the view that was clicked
                view = view.findViewWithTag(view.getTag());

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                int recordsUpdated = 0;

                if(upvoteButton.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thank you for voting ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    int newVotes = numVotes;
                    ++newVotes;

                    values.put(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_NUM_VOTES, String.valueOf(newVotes));
                    Uri uri = EventsContract.Events.buildEventUri(String.valueOf(event.getId()));
                    recordsUpdated = mContentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null);

                    //TODO: display the new vote;
                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_numVotes)).setText(newVotes + " Votes");
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "number of records updated = " + recordsUpdated + " newVotes: " + newVotes);

                } else {
                    //TODO: decrease vote
                    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_numVotes)).setText(numVotes + " Votes");
                    values.put(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_NUM_VOTES, String.valueOf(numVotes));
                    Uri uri = EventsContract.Events.buildEventUri(String.valueOf(event.getId()));
                    recordsUpdated = mContentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "number of records updated = " + recordsUpdated + "newVotes: " + numVotes);
                }
            }
        });

    return view;
}
public void setData(List<Event> events){
    clear();
    if(events != null){
        for(Event event : events){
            add(event);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The error thrown by the compiler shows that the null pointer exception happens at:

```
11-28 15:29:51.881 9724-9724/com.eventappucsd.mikesapplication        E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 15:29:51.881 9724-9724/com.eventappucsd.mikesapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.eventappucsd.mikesapplication, PID: 9724
11-28 15:29:51.881 9724-9724/com.eventappucsd.mikesapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: One or multiple of your TextView are null, log some to find out how it is...

Comment: All of the text fields are filled at the point when the app crashes. I can't figure out is why any of the TextView are null at that point (when I press the toggleButton). This is leading me to believe that I am not getting the correct View object to set the text to.

Comment: Consider logging the values to find out what is going on,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with this code. The problem seemed to be my old parameter

```
public void onClick(View view)
```

This was confusing syntax-wise, because it is meant to represent a different value than the View view that is outside of the OnClick method. The view in the getView method is what I needed in order to set the text in the TextView.

```
final ToggleButton upvoteButton = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.upbtn);
    upvoteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.upbtn:
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    int recordsUpdated = 0;

                    if(upvoteButton.isChecked()) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thank you for voting ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        int newVotes = numVotes;
                        ++newVotes;
                        //display the new vote count
                        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_numVotes)).setText(newVotes + " Votes");
                        //update
                        values.put(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_NUM_VOTES, String.valueOf(newVotes));
                        Uri uri = EventsContract.Events.buildEventUri(String.valueOf(event.getId()));
                        recordsUpdated = mContentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "number of records updated = " + recordsUpdated + " newVotes: " + newVotes);
                    }else {
                        //revert view for vote count
                        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_numVotes)).setText(numVotes + " Votes");
                        values.put(EventsContract.EventsColumns.EVENTS_NUM_VOTES, String.valueOf(numVotes));
                        Uri uri = EventsContract.Events.buildEventUri(String.valueOf(event.getId()));
                        recordsUpdated = mContentResolver.update(uri, values, null, null);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "number of records updated = " + recordsUpdated + " newVotes: " + numVotes);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    });
```